# Как программно получить ссылку на приложение в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Собственно я смотрю, что в некоторых приложения при нажатии `оставить отзыв` вызывается *Play Market*, а в некоторых открывается браузер и переходит на страницу приложения в *Google Play*.

Как первый способ работает не знаю, но во втором браузеру просто предается `url`,  но я же не знаю `url` своего приложения пока не загружу его в магазин значит и кнопку не могу создать? Или знаю?

Comment: Меня интересует как реализовать саму кнопку и где взять url на мой app. А предложенный ответ скорее дополняет мой вопрос а не отвечает на него.

Comment: Точно, так и есть

Comment: @BogdanShulga как мне кажется на Ваш вопрос ответили, а уж `как реализовать саму кнопку`?- Вы серьезно? - не сможете на форме разместить кнопку и в ее обработчик клика засунуть приведенные строки?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А вы пробовали смотреть на ссылку первого попавшегося приложения в Google Play? Выглядит она вот так:`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monstro.deadlyd`. Если на нее посмотреть хотя бы одним глазом, можно увидеть, что она состоит из `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` и вашего пакета приложения, в данном случае `com.monstro.deadlyd`

Вот универсальный код для любого приложения, который откроет ссылку на него в Google Play:

```
final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName(); //
try { 
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

Comment: Vladislav Matvienko, огромный сенк за ссылку. Интересовал вопрос, как делиться приложениями из PlayMarket`a, даже другое приложение устанавливал... ( Хотя, позже также нашёл более удобный способ - в TotalCmd есть опция "Отправить Url". Сори, если не совсем в тему!

Answer (score 7):

Если Вы ни разу не выливали приложение, то протестировать не сможете, но добавить эту кнопку можно сразу, и после того как ваше приложение пройдет модерацию, функциональность ее заработает. Url вашего приложения формируется из main package, типа такого 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your_package_name